# How does the link get into the selector?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, bootstrap-5

I have a very incomprehensible moment on the site on WordPress and WooCommerce.

I have this code that should show the drop-down list when clicking on "Buy Now"

```
<a href="https://new-car.net.ua/checkout/?buy-now=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Buy Now</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buy Left</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buy Right</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buy Both</a>
</div>
```

and script :

```
window.onload = function () {
  const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle')
  const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')
  toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    dropdownMenu.classList.toggle('show')
  })
}
```

But when I click on the link, an error appears in the console:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'https://new-car.net.ua/checkout/?buy-now=360' is not a valid selector.
At d (https://new-car.net.ua/wp-content/themes/storely/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=6.1.1:5:1573)

How did the link get into the selector if I specified document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle')?

Is this some kind of conflict with Bootstrap? How can I avoid it?

I can give you the code from the bootstrap that the error points to, but there is a lot of it, and it is minified.

```
    function s(t) {
        for (var e = 1; e < arguments.length; e++) {
            var n = null != arguments[e] ? arguments[e] : {};
            e % 2 ? o(Object(n), !0).forEach((function(e) {
                i(t, e, n[e])
            }
            )) : Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors ? Object.defineProperties(t, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(n)) : o(Object(n)).forEach((function(e) {
                Object.defineProperty(t, e, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(n, e))
            }
            ))
        }
        return t
    }
    t = t && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, "default") ? t.default : t;
    var r, a, l, c, u = function(t) {
        do {
            t += Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random())
        } while (document.getElementById(t));
        return t
    }, h = function(t) {
        var e = t.getAttribute("data-target");
        if (!e || "#" === e) {
            var n = t.getAttribute("href");
            e = n && "#" !== n ? n.trim() : null
        }
        return e
    }, f = function(t) {
        var e = h(t);
        return e && document.querySelector(e) ? e : null
    }, d = function(t) {
        var e = h(t);
        return e ? document.querySelector(e) : null //error is in this line
    },
```

Comment: Function `d` calls function `h`, which tries to find `data-target` attribute of the link, if it's not found, `href` is returned instead. `data-target` is not included in the link, hence `href` ends up to be used as a selector. To fix this, you've to set `data-target=".dropdown-menu"` for the link.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at the bootstrap code a little more carefully))